# Pass Value in JavaScript file from cakephp

Tags: javascript, cakephp-1.3

In my `test.ctp` file I write

```
<div class="Grid" id="grid1" style="width: 457px; height: 259px; z-index: 1;">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->webroot;?>js/test.js?id=<?php echo $id; ?>"></script>
</div>
```

and in `test.js` file I want to access this id value.how to get this value. Help me to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var id="",scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
for (var i=0,n=scripts.length, href="";i<n;i++) {
   href=scripts[i].src;
   if (href.indexOf("test.js") !=1) {
     id=href.split("?id=")[1];
     break;
   }
}
alert(id);
```

Alternatively

**1.** change the .js to .php

**2.** have this in the js file which is now a php file

```
<?php
header("content-type:text/javascript"); 
$ID=$_GET["id"]; // clean the var though
?>
var id = "<?php echo $ID; ?>";
```

**3.** call it

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="<?php echo $this->webroot."js/test.php?id=". $id; ?>">/script>
```